# Can't get vnc to connect

Tags: vnc

I have a server and my laptop. I want to be able to start vnc server on the server and then connect from my laptop. Both are running ubuntu 11.10 64 bit desktop

On my server, i installed tightvncserver. I set it up with a password, no view only password. I ssh to the box and typed

```
vncserver :42
```

Now on my laptop, I installed gtkvncviewer and ran it. It popped up a box. I entered the picard:42 (the name of the server in my /etc/hosts file) and the password. I tried with and without the user. It always disconnects immediately.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Is it because I'm not running a GUI session currently on picard? If so, how can I start the Xwindows session remotely to connect with vncserver?

Comment: i've added some hints how to proceed - does it work now?

Answer (score 1):

Which is the default runlevel? AFAIK this is configured in `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf`. Setting `DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL` to `2` should make the server start the X environment.
Alternatively, you could use ssh to start a complete gnome session on the server, displaying it on the client, using `ssh -X remote-user@server gnome-session`. But this will require some bandwith, so it may be better to start the desired application directly.

EDIT: here's the x11vnc command line to start the vnc server and let the remote user log into a gnome session:

```
sudo x11vnc -safer -localhost -once -nopw -auth /var/lib/gdm/:0.Xauth -display :0
```

(From the [Ubuntu Communitiy docs on VNC](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers#Connecting_to_your_login_screen))

Comment: Yes, 2 is the default run level and it is starting X Windows on the box. But I'm not sure why VNC is not working.

Comment: hmm - some points: if you've installed `x11vnc`, i would expect `x11vnc -safer -display :0` as command to start the server. Then: Did you try to increase debug output using the `-v` option (`x11vnc -v -display :0`)? Finally: If the `-v`option doesn't give any errors, you can re-check if the server is running using  `sudo netstat -atpn`. This will give you a list of services running and listening for connections.